# Error 00732 dataset does not exist or is not supported

Tags: python, arcpy

The error below occurs despite being able to hit the rest end of the service in the error.

```
import arcpy
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import datetime
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Users\arcfmun\Downloads\UtilityDataManagementSupport.atbx")

dirty_area_layer = "https://xxxx.xxx.com/arcgis/rest/services/DLCElectric/FeatureServer/970"

# Telemetry: Get Dirty Area Count before validation
before_da_count = arcpy.management.GetCount(dirty_area_layer).getOutput(0)
print(f"{before_da_count} dirty areas before validation")
```

> Start Time: 2023-05-16 22:15:21.011120
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\batchscripts\gis\MaintenanceScript\UNMaintenanceScript.py", line 36, in 
> before_da_count = arcpy.management.GetCount(dirty_area_layer).getOutput(0)
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 22045, in GetCount
> raise e
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 22042, in GetCount
> retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.GetCount_management(*gp_fixargs((in_rows,), True)))
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 512, in 
> return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
> ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset https://xxxx.xxx.com/arcgis/rest/services/DLCElectric/FeatureServer/970 does not exist or is not supported
> Failed to execute (GetCount).

Comment: You probably need to sign into the Portal, add in portal = GIS("url", "username", "password") where url is your portal url and username and password are your credentials.

Comment: Signing in to the portal is already included. I just put the portion of the script that causes the error in my post. 

Another thing to note is this error occurs randomly. Sometimes it works as expected, sometimes it fails on this part.